# Having problems shifting the characters of a string based on their ascii value

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tHdZ.png)Problem : "For this problem you will be implementing a Caesarin Cipher. A Caesarin Cipher takes a string and a shift amount and shifts the characters in the string by the shift amount to create an enciphered string. If a character would be shifted past the end of the alphabet then it wraps back around to the beginning. For example, if the shift amount was 1 then a -> b, b->c, c->d, ... y->z, and z->a."

I do not know what is going on; why my code refuses to work.

Comment: please post your code and what your input and expected output is ... otherwise i suspect you will get downvoted and/or closed (also please do not post images of code ... use the `{}` button in the markdown editor to make a codeblock  also `chr(ord('z') + amount)`  maybe isnt what you expect ...

Answer (score 0):

you have more than one problem, see below some explanation and a way to solve the issue:

1. new_user_input will be resetting each time you will iterate, so only the last character will be changed
2. the roll over could be apply using replace, but the problem is, it will return the full string and you will have to know which indexes has changed. You can revert the problem by parsing your input and pick the correct index.

A way of solving the problem:

```
def character_shifter():
    user_input = 'abz'
    shift = 2
    new_user_input = ''

    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    for c in user_input:
        assert c in alphabet, f"invalid entry {c} not in {alphabet}"
        reduce_chr = ord(c) - ord('a')   # you have to reduce to align 'a' with zero, after that you can use your list (otherwise you will have indexerror exception)
        shifted_chr = (reduce_chr + shift)   # apply shift value
        new_idx_alphabet = shifted_chr % len(alphabet)   # the roll over can be handled using modulus operator (e.g. 27 % 26 = 1)
        new_user_input += alphabet[new_idx_alphabet]  # add char by char, the chr shifted

    print(new_user_input)
```